# Trying to understand S corp

Tags: united-states, income-tax, small-business, s-corporation

Say an S Corp has one owner and earns 300k in a year. It pays wages of 100k.  Can the 200k be invested by the S Corp so that the the 200k does not have to be distributed?

Comment: Invested *where*?  (If stocks and bonds, or "investing in" car that the owner's teen daughter exclusively drives, I don't think the IRS auditors would be very understanding.  If investing a new warehouse to grow the business, they'd see that as a valid business expense.)

Comment: @RonJohn - I don't know if OP meant invested in anything specifically. I took it to mean: leave it in the company's bank account for future use (buying tools, inventory, hiring employees, etc).

Comment: @TTT he definitely needs to clarify that.

Comment: @RonJohn - agreed, that would make it clearer. But leaving undistributed profits in an s-corp is commonly called "reinvesting" the profits. (Maybe OP just left off the "re".)

Comment: @RonJohn,  I currently own LLC and work as software consultant,  I don't have any real expenses and am not planning on hiring people or buying new equipment.  I was thinking of just putting money in mutual fund.

Comment: @steviekm3 - note that if you buy/sell stocks within the company, you still have to pay capital gains personally when they are realized, just like the other income tax you have to pay personally, even if you don't distribute the "gains". So, for a single owner s-corp, I can't think of any advantage to keeping money in the company and buying stocks/funds, vs distributing it and buying the stocks/funds personally. (Doesn't mean there isn't one, I just can't think of one at the moment.)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but your use of the phrase "so that the the 200k does not have to be distributed" makes it seem like you're thinking distributions are mandatory, which isn't the case. Distributions are optional; nothing forces you to distribute the profits; you could leave the money in the company bank account if you wish or even "invest" in mutual funds or real estate.

Note the $200K profit would flow to the S-Corp owner as regular income, and income tax on that amount would be owed. Typically you would distribute enough to cover the tax owed, but you aren't required to. If you have enough personal funds to pay the tax without distributing it you can leave the entire $200K profit to *reinvest* in the company.

I'm going to assume that the $100K in wages is going to the owner too (because the owner should be taking a reasonable salary), in which case you would pay both sides of the FICA taxes on the $100K and income tax, whereas with the $200K profits only the income tax is owed *whether you distribute it or not*.

As a side note, your profits will actually be less than $200K, since you will certainly have deductions, one of which is at least 7.65% on the $100K for the employer portion of FICA.

Comment: "I'm going to assume that the $100K in wages is going to the owner too".  Why can't it be a couple of employees (secretary and salesman, for example)?

Comment: @RonJohn - it absolutely can be, but typically the owner should take a reasonable salary too, unless it is entirely passive income.

Comment: And I don't think it explicitly answers the question "**Can the 200k be invested** by the S Corp so that the the 200k does not have to be distributed?"

Comment: Does the owner take a *salary* or take regular distributions (which effectively mimic a salary, but tax wise are different)?

Comment: @RonJohn - both. Owners who are involved in the business must take a reasonable salary. On top of that they can take distributions if they wish. Since distributions avoid FICA taxes, taking a very low salary is frowned upon.

Comment: @RonJohn - I edited to address "can the 200k be invested", in case OP was actually asking about investments and/or thought distributions were required.

Comment: Seems FICA is the main benefit of S-corp.   Suppose an s-corp made 650k gross revenue and only expense was 100k wages of an employee.  The employee was the owner.   What advantages are there tax wise from this S-corp over an LLC that made 650k ?  Once concern is the 20% deduction that was in the tax law for pass through entities from a couple of years ago.  This deduction phases out at certain income levels.  Is there any way for S-corp with 650k revenue to get around this 20% deduction phase out where the only expense is the salary of the owner ?  Maybe pay more or less of a salary.

Comment: @steviekm3 - you're correct that FICA is the main benefit of an S-corp. Note you'll max out SS at $137.7K but Medicare will persist for all profits with the LLC. Note there is an option for LLCs to be taxed like an S-Corp which essentially makes them nearly equivalent. The 20% pass-through deduction is based on your individual income, not business, so you'd have to reduce the company profit to keep your total personal income under the limit to qualify. If you're close to the cutoff it might make sense to increase your business expenses enough to lower profits, but probably not at $650k.

Comment: @steviekm3 - increasing salary wouldn't help either because that would still increase your personal income. Perhaps one way to think about this is: when you make so much money that you're phased out of the 20% deduction, that's a good thing and just be happy about it. ;)